# Shellscript: Conditional operator: What is wrong in following shellscript if statement

Tags: bash, shell

Here is my shellscript if condition

```
if [[ $RBFilePath =~ \.js$ || $RBFilePath =~ \.json$ && ${#key_array[0]} = "JAVASCRIPT" ]]; then
Blah blah
blah blah

fi
```

What I want here is, if `$RBFilePath` ends with `.js` or `.json` **AND** First elemeny of array: `key_array` is **equal** to `"JAVASCRIPT"` then execute the if block.

But it is not executing. Can someone please help telling me issue.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement is *incorrect* as it checks the *length* of the first element of the array

```
${#key_array[0]} = "JAVASCRIPT"
```

change it to

```
${key_array[0]} = "JAVASCRIPT"
```

which checks the value of the first element in the array.

e.g.

```
fooArray=('foo' 'bar')
printf "%s\n" "${#fooArray[0]}"
3
printf "%s\n" "${fooArray[0]}"
foo
```

Comment: No No no.. How did I miss this basic :(

Comment: @OmSao: It happens to the best of us! ;)

Comment: One thing to confirm, Is using single Equal `=` for condition is best practice or should we use `==` ?

Comment: @OmSao: I would use `==` as a best practice

Comment: Ok, but both `=` and `==` works fine as I tested. Thanks @Inian !